# Using Crypto++ to sign using private key; SHA1 vs Whirlpool

Tags: digital-signature, c++

I'm using crypto++ according to the RSA-PSSR-Filter-Test.zip example [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Digital_signature) and it works.

I'm trying to find something I can use reliably for signing a message with private key and verifying its origin with public key programmatically in a Qt app.

I am happy I can actually get the message extracted while verifying the signature:

```
        StringSource(signature, true,
        new SignatureVerificationFilter(
            verifier,
            new StringSink(recovered),
            SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION | SignatureVerificationFilter::PUT_MESSAGE) // SignatureVerificationFilter
    ); // StringSource

    assert(ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText().toStdString() == recovered);
```

But SHA1 is unsafe.

Then I found [this example](http://marko-editor.com/articles/cryptopp_sign_string/) with Whirlpool. However, it doesn't seem to extract the actual original message, just claims to verify it.Does this code actually verify the message though? The ArraySink usage seems a bit esoteric to me so I can't tell.

```
  bool result = false;
  Verifier verifier(publicKey);
  CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(decodedSignature + aMessage, true,
                         new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(verifier,
                           new CryptoPP::ArraySink((byte*)&result,
                                                   sizeof(result))));

  return result;
```

I tried to convert the code to be similar to the SHA1 example but this does not extract any message:

```
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(decodedSignature, true,
        new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(verifier,
            new StringSink(recovered)));
```

Is it possible to convert this code with Whirlpool to actually extract the message from the signature, or is the actual message not contained in the signature although it appears to be PSSR?

I am also wondering about the usage of 'new' allocations here; does this code actually leak memory?

My apologies for any erroneous terminology; I am not in the security field.

Comment: Sha3 is considered backdoored you should use the original Keccak implementation

Comment: How about Whirlpool then? :)

Comment: @user6858980 That's a strong claim. Can you provide a reference? If that's true, then I have some software to go re-write ...

Comment: https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc

plenty on google also

Comment: That seems to say that Etherium chose Keccak before the SHA3 spec was available, and then does some general tin-foil-hattery about the NSA, but does not actually accuse SHA3 of being backdoored. [Bruce Schneier said](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/will_keccak_sha-3.html) (quoting from the EDIT at the end) _"I do not believe that the NIST changes were suggested by the NSA. Nor do I believe that the changes make the algorithm easier to break by the NSA. I believe NIST made the changes in good faith, and the result is a better security/performance trade-off."_. Seems like I'm safe

Comment: Would someone please be interested in responding ANY of my questions?  or is this more suitable for stack overflow?

Comment: Yes, this question is more suitable for stack overflow since it's a programming question. Hold tight, it'll be auto-migrated once it gets 2 more migration votes.

Comment: Thanks. Well how about whirlpool reliability?

Comment: This is being discussed at 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/AARfaNKNQRs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the original [RSA-PSSR-Filter-Test.zip example](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Digital_signature) can be modified to use SHA3, by using enum value SHA3_512 for instance instead of SHA1 where it occurs. (You will also need to modify some header includes and using directives.) Still not sure why I couldn't get the response out from the Whirlpool example. More details on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/AARfaNKNQRs).